# iOS Use multiple CollectionView reusing the same cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to iOS programming but from my experience with Android i know that you can create one design for a item that can be reused in multiple lists, without needing to create a copy.

In iOS i have been trying the same approach with UICollectionView.

In my view i have created three Horizontal UICollectionViews (with different data sets) which in turn use their own cell (Which is identical to the others). I don't know how to make the other two collections use the first ones cell, so i don't need to recreate the same cell over and over.

Comment: If you are using a storyboard then you need to create the prototype cell 3 times but you can use the same custom class for each cell.

Comment: You can use a xib for the cell that you'd reuse registering it for each collection view.

Comment: Nice!, do you have an example i can follow? link?

Comment: @Oreex0 Look for "Custom UICollectionViewCell Xib Swift", you should get plenty of questions or tutorials. Some of them might be in "Old Swift", but finding the new version of the method should be easy with the autocomplete because the whole logic remained the same. If you understand a little Objective-C, you could find tutorial too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` you can inform your collectionview which cell to use

if you have define your cell you might have something similar to this

```
 class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    var Label: UILabel!
    var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

so into your function `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` you need to inform your collectionview which cell to use

```
collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell:MyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell
[...]
}
```

and dont forget to register your cell first

```
override func viewDidLoad() {        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //do your stuff
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        collectionView.registerClass(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
}
```

and Voila !

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i have been playing around with this and now i'm getting nil on unwrapping..
From cell.label

Comment: The xib file has my class and "cell" as identifier. 
In the storyboard CollectionView i set the cell to the same identifier and class.

Comment: Solved it, ised registerNib(UINib.init(nibname: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forcell..:"myCell_identifier")

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve this using single storyboard. If you want to use Interface Builder (xml) file for layout, you should create MyCell.xib file, then drag UICollectionViewCell on that file and work with that xib.
Then you should connect .xib file with your collection view like this:

`let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil)
collectionView?.register(nil, for: "MyCellReuseID")`

And you can work with your cell now.

Also you can create MyCell: UICollectionViewCell class without creating .xib file, create views on it programmatically and then call `collectionView?.register(MyCell.self, for: "MyCellReuseID")`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new file collection cell with XIB
2. In your "item at row for index" delegate method in view controller, initialize cell and return it.
3. Now any collection view within you view controller have the same cell

Comment: go to this link for complete tutorial http://samwize.com/2016/04/06/using-custom-uicollectionviewcell-xib-in-storyboard/

Answer (score 0):

Create a Swift class(CollectionViewCell) by having `UICollectionViewCell` as a base class. Select create nib option while doing that.

Then create a view controller and add collection view to it in your storyboard and hook up this custom cell class in `Identity Inspector`. Basically, your structure needs to look like below

[image]